# html input to canvas accept backspace

Tags: javascript, canvas

I tried using keydown and keyup its showing in canvas, but when I press 'backspace' or delete the text still not delete.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// do cool things with the context
context.font = '40pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
$('input').keydown(function(e){
        
  if(e.keyCode==8)
  {
    var newvalue = $(this).val();
    context.fillText(newvalue, 150, 100);
  }
});
$('input').keyup(function(){
  context.fillText($(this).val(), 150, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: A canvas does not work like that, you need to clear and redraw it (or add to the drawing). A canvas is metaphoprically like a painting, you are painting text on it - it is not live mimicking what you are doing. You probably need `canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)` to clear and then redraw the text once it has changed. Right now you are painting the same text over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your canvas before the redraw to remove any already filled pixels:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

As you might have noticed, it didn't delete your character, but if you typed another character it also overlayed it over the previous one - that's why you need to clear before redraw.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// do cool things with the context
context.font = '40pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
$('input').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==8){
    var newvalue = $(this).val();
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.fillText(newvalue, 150, 100);
  }
});
$('input').keyup(function(){
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  context.fillText($(this).val(), 150, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below snippet, You can use **clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height)** to clear the Canvas. 
I think you don't really need both keyup & keydown event.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // do cool things with the context
 context.font = '40pt Calibri';
 context.fillStyle = 'blue';

 $('input').keyup(function() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0,  canvas.width,canvas.height);
   context.fillText($(this).val(), 150, 100);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```